# Hiring freelancers in Germany

Tags: european-union, tax-law, germany, work-for-hire

This question is the counterpart to [Tax law and freelancing as a side-job in Germany](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/43821/tax-law-and-freelancing-as-a-side-job-in-germany/43824#43824).

What are the laws concerning hiring a freelancer for a short project (for example an international freelancer through an Internet platform like UpWork) in Germany? What kind of contract should be formed and what kind of taxes are involved (on the part of the "buyer"?

Comment: This question is way too broad.

Comment: @StephanS What additional information would make it easier to answer?

Comment: the problem isn't that there isn't enough information, the problem is to answer the question requires extensive knowledge of Germany's tax, employment, contract, and immigration law. If the question was chunked into several different parts it might be easier to answer, but to answer it in its current form would require a full "report".